# How to deal with $\overline{\mathbb R}$ to avoid indeterminate forms in this case?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f, g: \Omega \to \overline{\mathbb R}$ be two measurable functions. How can I show that the sets $A = \{\omega \in \Omega: f(\omega) - g(\omega) < 0\}$ and $B = \{\omega \in \Omega: f(\omega) - g(\omega) = 0\}$ are measurable.
I tried to define $h(\omega) = f(\omega) - g(\omega)$ and show that it is measurable but I don't know how to deal correctly with the cases in which $f$ and $g$ are both $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: The question doesn't state how $\infty-\infty$ or $(-\infty)-(-\infty)$ are defined.

Comment: @O.Peters: That´s what I wanted to know. How should I define them in order to have $h$ well defined and use it to show meaurability of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: You can make sense of $f<g$ and $f=g$ but that is not the same as $f-g<0$ and $f-g=0$.